# How to find a GCC version which contains a certain version of libstdc++.so?

Tags: gcc, g++, libstdc++

With my knowledge, `libstdc++.so` is bundled with `g++` and will be installed when installing a `g++`. However, if I want to install a certain version of `libstdc++.so`, how can I know which version of `g++` (or `gcc`) should I install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [the this section of appendix B](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html) of the libstdc++ manual, which contains a list of gcc and libstdc++ version numbers.